# In Git, How do I checkout to a New Branch from an already Existing Branch?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-checkout

I am a Ruby on Rails programming novice and new to VCS as well. I will explain my question with an example:

**Scenario**: I have created an rails application base using `rails new AppName`. An empty git repository is created by default with *HEAD -> master*. I have Staged and commited changes. Now I run `git checkout -b new-branch-1`. It creates a new branch and checks out to it. Now I made some changes in this branch and commited those changes.

**Question 1**: Now, If I want to create a new branch and checkout to it, and the branch should have the changes I made in `new-branch-1`. What command should I run and which branch should I run it from?

**Question 2**: Does it matter, from which branch I run the command?

> P.S: need not to involve remote repos

I tried the same as mentioned above. Just need better clarity.

Comment: If you're on `new-branch-1` use `git checkout -b new-branch-2`. _"Does it matter, from which branch I run the command?"_ yes.

Comment: You're going to have to explain where you got your idea of what a branch is, and what exactly the command you're looking for is supposed to do, because by a plain reading just `git help checkout` would get you to `git checkout -b newbranch oldbranch` and surely whatever question you've really got, it's not just that one.

Comment: @jthill that really helped. I didn't know that sourcebranch can be passed as argument for this command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1:
To create a new branch and have it include the changes you made in new-branch-1, you can do this:

> git checkout -b new-branch-2 new-branch-1

This command will create a new branch named new-branch-2 based on the current branch new-branch-1. It will copy all the changes from new-branch-1 to the new branch, and then check out to the newly created new-branch-2.

Q2:
The branch from which you run the command does not matter. You can be on any branch when executing the git checkout -b command. The new branch will be created based on the specified source branch (in this case, new-branch-1) regardless of the branch you are currently on.